# Vertical Scrollable list of words, and changing font-size and opacity based on position

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, vertical-scrolling

I'm trying to create a vertical scrollable "word list" within a sentence. The catch is that i need to alter the opacity and size of that word, based on the position in the list (see the image).

[image: What i want to achieve]

I can somewhat achieve this using react-slick, but the scrolling feels very sluggish. Any takers?